# Apache Camel: Is there any way to set a message to fault without injecting the exchange in a bean method?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm totally new to Apache Camel, after finished the "Camel in Action", I am still not so clear about a basic function. Is there any way the set a message to be a fault message without injecting the exchange in bean method.

Here I can provide a example:

```
class HttpBean{
    public void parseIP(@Properties Map properties,@XPath("//ip") String ip){
        properties.put("IP", ip);
    }
}
```

A method named "parseIP" is designed to parse ip in the body using xpath and save its value in a property map. But if there's no ip tag in body at all, I want to create a fault message and terminate the process(Not just throw a exception which will be treated as a recoverable error, Here I want a unrecoverable error). To achieve this goal, I can use the following code:

```
class HttpBean{
    public void parseIP(@Properties Map properties,@XPath("//ip") String ip, Exchange exchange){
        if(ip == null){
            exchange.getIn().setFault(true);
            exchange.getIn().setBody("Ip is missing");
        }
        properties.put("IP", ip);
    }
}
```

But is this the best solution? Because once I inject an exchange into a bean method, I think it's not different than a camel processor and I lose most of its advantage. A bean in camel can finish its own work without using any Camel specific API, but once the exchange is injected, the advantage is gone.

Someone can help me with the question? Thanks a lot.

Comment: include the route that you are using to call this bean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just set a fault from the route based on the results of the bean...if property IP is null, then set fault, etc...

```
@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {

            from("direct:route1")
                .bean(new HttpBean())
                .filter(property("IP").isNull()).setFaultBody(constant("Ip is missing")).end()
                .to("mock:mock");
        }
    };
}

public static class HttpBean {
    public void parseIP(@Properties Map properties, @XPath("//ip") String ip){
        if(ip != null && ip.length() > 0){
            properties.put("IP", ip);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it's a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone runs across this question and are looking for details on how to set Soap Faults from CXF in POJO, Message, or Payload mode, take a look at this link from Talend:

https://help.talend.com/display/TalendESBMediationDeveloperGuide54EN/3.8.10+How+to+throw+a+SOAP+Fault+from+Camel

Here is a code snippet:

```
    SoapFault fault = new SoapFault("unable to process request", SoapFault.FAULT_CODE_SERVER);
    Element detail = fault.getOrCreateDetail();

    Document detailPayload = getYourDetailHere();
    detail.appendChild(detail.getOwnerDocument().importNode(detailPayload.getDocumentElement(), true));

    Message outMessage = exchange.getOut();
    outMessage.setHeader(org.apache.cxf.message.Message.RESPONSE_CODE, new Integer(500));
    outMessage.setFault(true);

    outMessage.setBody(fault);
```